# What will happen if HDFS client failed to upload the file?

Tags: hadoop, transactions, hdfs

In my understanding, uploading files to HDFS (the filesystem for Apache Hadoop) follows the below procedures:

- 1. client (hdfs shell) asks Namenode which datanodes to put the data chunks
- 2. Namenode answers it and saves the files location and some metadata in itself
- 3. client puts the data chunks to the given datanodes

Suppose, in 1, Namenode returned which datanode to store the data. However, after that, the datanode gets unavailable because of some reasons (e.g. Network failure or Machine outage). So, the data cannot be saved in datanode but the metadata is stored in Namenode. The data gets inconsistent state.

Can someone explain how HDFS is avoiding this situation? I tried to read hadoop source code but I finally gave up because it's huge.

Comment: Are you asking if it fails to write to a single data node, or all nodes in the replica set? The possible answer is that there is just a corrupt block in the Namenode; the other solution is that the metadata isnt actually persisted in the Namenode until the datanode acks the transaction

Comment: When datanode acks, client will call `commit` to namenode right? If the namenode could not receive the commit (due to network outage), will it make data inconsistency?

Comment: Not if the replication factor is enough to work for the rest of the datanodes. If they all fail to communicate (which indicates a single point of failure in your network configuration}, then the write would fail overall